# Android "text" next to "Text Field" box

Tags: android, text, textfield

Im newbie into Android development and I have a silly question. How do you place the "text field" box next to a text in a single line.

Example:

```
Please Enter the number:   [        ] <--- this should be the textfield.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `LineraLayout` (or) `RelativeLayout` (or) `TableLayout`.

Here is good example: [Android Layout Tutorial](http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/4/)

Answer (score 3):

As the others said above..you would have to put them in a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. Since you're just starting out I suggest going with LinearLayout instead. Something like this should work.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<TextView android:text="Please Enter The Number:"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width = "wrap_content"/>

<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys. This worked like a charm. I want to take control over the EditTex like giving them the distance from the edges

Comment: If this answered your original question, please submit it as an answer. Also, from what I get from your follow up question the "distance from the edges" you're looking for is an attribute called padding. Add this line to your TextView or EditText tag.      android:padding = "5dp". There is also other Properties you can use in the Visual Editor just right click the widget and then ->Properties. I suggest you play around with Layout Gravity, LayoutMarginRight, LayoutPadding, etc. Those will give you more control over the display and position of your views

Answer (score 0):

You put them side by side in a horizontal LinearLayout for example. Or in two columns in a TableLayout. And btw. the components to use are TextView and EditText

Comment: Do you have an example? Thanks